# Did my Raspberry Zero W Burn?

Tags: sd-card, power, boot-issues

I'm new to Raspberry PI, On my first attempt to power it up, I connected the usb slot to power using a cell phone charger (output: 5V, 2A). and I did not insert the SD card. once I connected the cell phone charger to power, a sort of power surge occurred in the Raspberry and a burning smell came out. Did I damage it?and why? is it because I tried to boot it without the SD card or because there is too much power?
If it is burned, I will buy another one but I need to know if there is a specific power output it receives.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. From your description that sure does sound not very promissing - burning smell and the blue magic smoke escaping from the circuit is usually not a good sign. However, if you just connected a standard power adapter with a pre-made connector to the Pi there is little that should have gone wrong (such as mixing up polarity).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing bad should happen to a new Pi (with or without an SD card) when you plug it into a 5V charger. The charger will only supply as much current as is needed by the Pi. In this instance, either your Pi was shipped with a fault or your power supply has a fault.

If it were mine, I would return the Pi as faulty and do some further testing on the power supply to make sure I didn't fry the replacement. Ideally you should be supplying between 5V and 5.25V, and at least 1A (more if there are connected USB peripherals).

Comment: ok thanks guys, yes , I will return it. I just wanted to make sure it is my fault before returning it (and that I will not burn another one).

Comment: The user connected the charger to the usb port instead of the power port. You may have missed that part.

Comment: @Mike It's a little unclear exactly which socket they connected the power to. It doesn't make a lot of difference - the zero should fire up regardless.